# Map Windows key to Ctrl key

Tags: keyboard, windows, google-chrome, remote-desktop

I am using a MacBook Pro & a Windows PC.

I use Google Chrome's Remote Desktop to control the MacBook from the Windows PC.

It works well but on the Windows PC, I have to use the <kbd>Win</kbd> key to copy & paste and <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Is there any way we can map the Window desktop key to the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key? so that I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> even when I use the MacBook via Chrome's Remote Desktop?

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Comment: Have you asked support for Google Chrome Remote Desktop for Windows?  That's probably where any remapping has to happen.

Comment: I have already asked it.

Answer (score 0):

When connecting via Google Remote Desktop, You can check the settings under "INPUT CONTROLS" for remapping the keys or configuring the keyboard shortcuts as per the requirement.

[image]